# How to set up an OSM vector tile server

Tags: openstreetmap, vector, tiles, json

I have to set up a server for querying JSON tiles coming from OSM data. Hosting the data myself is a requirement as the load is expected to become quite high.

I spent the last days looking for solutions but can't find one that allows scaling and returns JSON tiles - I absolutely don't need raster maps. Note that I don't need to edit the tiles or anything, the server only needs to serve the tiles as they are.

I already have a database with the required OSM data.

Could anyone with experience point me towards the right technology to use to serve these JSON tiles?